# core-image-sato-dev does not include gcc

Tags: yocto

This is the first time I am building yocto images. I first read [this list of images](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/images.html) in the documentation and selected `core-image-sato-dev`, since I wanted to have some image where I could do some hello world .

The doc says

> core-image-sato-dev: A core-image-sato image suitable for development
> using the host. The image includes libraries needed to build
> applications on the device itself, testing and profiling tools, and
> debug symbols. This image was formerly core-image-sdk.

Something that I misunderstood was that the development is *using the host*

Yes, I cannot find gcc in `/usr/bin`. So this image does not have the c compiler (it has make though)

So what should I do?  Is there a way to add it? Or should I go for `core-image-sato-sdk`??

What exactly does this imply?

> core-image-sato-sdk: A core-image-sato image that includes everything
> in the cross-toolchain. The image also includes development headers
> and libraries to form a complete standalone SDK and is suitable for
> development using the target.

Answer (score 0):

GCC or any other compiler is not meant to be part of that image. As the quote from the docs you've provided says, `The image includes libraries needed to build applications on the device itself`.

All `core-image-sato-dev` does it inherits `core-iamge-sate` and adds `dev-pkgs` to `IMAGE_FEATURES` which ships `development packages`.

What you're looking for is `tools-sdk` in `IMAGE_FEATURES`.